# system calls on goldfish emulator which is running with a self-compiled kernel

Tags: android-emulator, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, ioctl

I have written a driver for embedded Linux kernel goldfish 3.4. Now I want to test my `ioctl` system call from a device driver I wrote in the `\dev` director. During a lot tutorial online all suggest writing a simple user-space programme c to test. However, I have no idea how to do it in an embedded environment like goldfish. It is an emulator for an Android phone.

`static int goldfish_accel_ioctl(struct file* fp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg){
switch(cmd){
    case TEST:
      printk(KERN_ALERT"Hello world ioctl!");
}
}`

I have register a special file in the `dev\` directory called `accelrometer`

Hope my description makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution finally and share it here in case someone has the same issue as me.

Apparently, the Linux kernel I run (At least the goldfish emulator with adb shell) have a built-in `ioctl` command.

Usage:

`ioctl \dev yourDevice cmd`

Noted cmd is an integer that you retrieve it from `_IO(MAGIC_NUMBER, n)` inside of your driver. You can use module parameters to get them in userspace if you cannot write a userspace library to test your `ioctl`.